# If $p$ and $q$ are positive prime numbers such that $p$ is divisible by $q$, show that $p = q$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To solve this problem, this is my approach. Assume $p\mid q$, there exists an $n∈N$ and assume $q\mid p$, there exists an $m∈N$. This would mean that $p=qn$ and $q=pm$. Then using substitution, $p=pmn$ where either $p=0$ or $mn=1$. If $mn=1$, then  $n=m=1$ and if $p=0$, then $q$ is also $0$ which means that $p=q$. However, the question states that $p$ and $q$ are primes, so does my approach work or is there something else? Help appreciated please.

Comment: Which definition of "prime" are you using?

Comment: Aside the fact that this is merely checking the definition, your proof uses $p\mid q$ which wasn't in the hypothesis. In fact you never used "primality", therefore your "result" holds for any number, but there exists at least 2 different integer numbers therefore something wrong:):)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $q\mid p$. Since $p$ is prime, then there are only two divisors of $p$, namely $1$ and $p$. So, $q=1$ or $q=p$. Since $q$ is prime, $q>1$, so $q\neq1$. Thus, $q=p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Every prime number $p$ has only two positive divisors, $1$ and $p$. If $q|p$ then how many divisors would at least $p$ have if $p \neq q$? Now conclude.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track up until the point you decided to use substitution. So back up to just before that point.

If $p = qn$ and $p$ is prime, then $n = 1$ or $n = -1$. The former means $p = q$, as desired, the latter means $p = -q$. But I have a feeling your textbook is concerned with positive primes only.